# Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException for exactly one record in DB

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Checking in db with hibernate-generated query and see exactly one record but for repository method call got `Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2`

Don't even know where to look.

Comment: Can you add the repo and calling code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It was issue of implementation - business logic has two part deletion then persisting, - deletion part failed quietly, so after persisting there was two instances matching search criteria. I apologize.